# iPhone 8 - Calendar lost items from early 2020

Tags: data-synchronization, calendar

I have the correct settings on my phone to sync to the Cloud, and have it save all my calendar items, but the beginning of 2020 has lost all its entries.  Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Check
Settings > Calendar > Sync

There are options to sync back from 2 weeks to 6 months, or 'all events'.

Comment: My phone has been set to All Events for several months.  That is why I am unsure why the calendar items show in Yahoo Mail, but are gone from my iPhone.